# RESTEasy and client IP address

Tags: java, resteasy

I'm using RESTEasy services in my application and now I'm forced to get the clients IP addresses.  So the question is... how can I do that?.
  Thanks in advance

**EDITED** I've just came to a solution with servlet filter... but still.. can that be done inside of RESTEasy service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can annotate a Context in your resource like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Response getMe(
            final @PathParam("id") String id,
            @Context HttpServletRequest req) {

     System.err.println(req.getRemoteAddr());
```

Comment: This works well, but if you're behind a web server (Apache for instance), it will give you the IP of the server instead. If you want to get the actual IP of the original request, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797/how-do-i-get-the-remote-address-of-a-client-in-servlet.