# conflict of IP address in java

Tags: java, ip-address

I have tried obtaining my computer's IP address in two different ways. The first way was to just Google `ip address`. The second way was to run the following code in Java:

```
public class YourIPAddress {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  InetAddress ip;
  try {

    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println(ip);
    System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

}

}
```

Google returns `50.90.142.29` whereas Java returns `192.168.0.11`. Why this conflict in IP addresses?

Comment: One is the external IP address of your router.  The other is your computer's IP address on your local network.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of NAT - [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), whicho is how almost all residential, and many business networks are set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192.160.0.11 is the private / internal ip address while 50.90.142.29 is the public / external ip address

Comment: Which the private IP address would be the address of my router? http://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip

Comment: the private address on your router is likely 192.168.0.1.  192.168.0.11 is likely the private ip of your computer

Comment: and then another question, about the application of this (the reason why I am asking this question): if you make a program for a user that submits data to your computer, would you (the client) need to know their private or public IP address? If public, how would you, in Java, obtain such information as simply as possible?

Comment: EDIT: The answer might be the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java

Comment: you would need to get the remote address of the client from your servlet, like the best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797/how-do-i-get-the-remote-address-of-a-client-in-servlet  request.getRemoteAddr(); but also check for the proxy cases like that response does

Comment: For the reference of anyone having my question who is clueless on what a servlet is, it is simply a conforming Java Server Class: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlet

Comment: EDIT: The example they have at that link is a METHOD, not a class. My question is, now, is a ServerSocket a servlet?