# retrieving client IP address in jax-rs resteasy interceptor

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a REST Webservice API which I need to secure by several criterias. Here is a stripped example of my interceptor:

```
    @Provider
    @ServerInterceptor
    public class MySecurityInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        private static final ServerResponse ACCESS_FORBIDDEN = new ServerResponse( "Nobody can access this resource", 403, new Headers<Object>() );;

        private static final ServerResponse SERVER_ERROR = new ServerResponse( "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", 500, new Headers<Object>() );;

        @Override
        public void filter( ContainerRequestContext requestContext ) throws IOException {
            ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker)requestContext.getProperty( "org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker" );
            Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();

            if ( !method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent( ApiKey.class ) ) {
                requestContext.abortWith( SERVER_ERROR );
                RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException("...");
                throw e;
            }

            if ( method.isAnnotationPresent( PermitAll.class ) ) { //Everyone can call method
                return;
            }

            // -- No one
            if ( method.isAnnotationPresent( DenyAll.class ) ) {
                requestContext.abortWith( ACCESS_FORBIDDEN );
                return;
            }

            //... And so on
        }
    }
```

In case of PermitAll I need to add an IP-Check. How can I obtain the caller IP adress at this place?

Comment: Inject the `HttpServletRequest` and obtain the IP-Address [like explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797).

Answer (score 3):

The [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) class provides a rich API to get request-specific information, such as the request URI, headers, entity, cookies or request-scoped properties. But, unfortunatelly, it does not provide information about the client IP address.

The way to go is inject the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) in your filter:

```java
@Context
HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

And then extract the client IP address using [`ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr--).

---

<sup>**Note:** Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227) for other types that can be injected with [`@Context`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html).</sup>