# How to get the IP address of users visiting my localsite

Tags: jsp, ip-address

Im currently deploying my app using apache tomcat 7. I want to get the Ip addressess of users who visit my local site so that i could keep tract the number of visits per IP address. Could someone help me? I bet HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() only returns the 127.0.0.1.
Im using JSP/Servlet for this.

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797/how-do-i-get-the-remote-address-of-a-client-in-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
   if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
   }
```

Comment: That only returns 127.0.0.1

Comment: Seems like your apache web server is redirecting to this 127.0.0.1 based on Rewrite rules

Comment: @AdrianMesa you are accessing you web url from your local system that's why you are getting this ip `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

To get remote IP/LOCAL IP address you need to know about HTTP Headers where you can get all poosible headers which you required use below code to get headers name and their values.

```
java.util.Enumeration em = request.getHeaderNames();

    while(em.hasMoreElements()){

    String key = (String)em.nextElement();
    key = key.trim();
    System.out.println("Header Name :: "+key+"||Header Value ::"+reqeust.getHeader(key));

    }
```

Implement above code in your project and access your website from another system or server and trace all above headers values. Hope you will find what do you want!