# When HttpServletRequest getHeader return unknown?

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, http-headers, clientip

I am using the below code (Copied from another post - [How do I get the remote address of a client in servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797/how-do-i-get-the-remote-address-of-a-client-in-servlet)) to get the client IP address along with the proxy server (SpringBoot Appln deployed in PCF).

```
  public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
      ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
      ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
      ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
      ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
    {
      ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ip;
  }
```

request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For"); /request.getRemoteAddr(); (when run from local) gives the expected result. I really didn't understand the uses of other conditions.

1. In all conditions I see "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(IP) is used. But when I try to access request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP") or any junk string, I am getting null.
   When HttpServletRequest getHeader return unknown? Can this be ignored?
2. What is the use of Proxy-Client-IP/HTTP_CLIENT_IP. I guess it is used to get client IP alone (without proxy server IP). Is it specific to a particular server? if so which server. 
   Can this be ignored in Spring boot application
3. I guess 'WL-Proxy-Client-IP' is specific to WebLogic. Can this be ignored as well?
4. I believe the HTTP_ prefix is specific to PHP (HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP.) Is it necessary in the SpringBoot application?
5. I feel the below code is more than enough to get the client IP address along with the proxy server (provided I use spring boot with embedded tomcat and deploy the code in PCF). Could you please confirm?

   ```
   private static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
   {
     String clientIp = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");

     if (clientIp == null || clientIp.length() == 0)
     {
       clientIp = httpRequest.getRemoteAddr();
     }
     return clientIp;
   }
   ```

Comment: so what is the problem with the way that you are doing it?  It seems a more robust solution to how you are proposing and to my quick glance, if `X-Forwarded-For` is set then the result would be the same.

Comment: Sonaqube is complaining that the Cyclomatic Complexity of this method is greater than authorized. I can fix the issue by other ways but I just don't want to have junk unused code. Also, It affects cover coverage. I just want to make sure before deleting the un used code.

Comment: *I guess 'WL-Proxy-Client-IP' is specific to WebLogic. Can this be ignored as well*  - it is your environment so you should know better

Comment: @Thiagarajan Ramanathan, please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350318/what-is-the-right-way-to-get-requests-ip

Comment: Just create a list of header names to check, iterate through them and when one comes back use that. The stuff inside the `if` statements is always the same. One addition you might want to do is convert the `ip` to a `String[]`. potentially when multiple routers are involved the `X-Forwarded-For` becomes a comma separated list of multiple IPs. Where the first one is the IP you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this.

```
public class HttpRequestHelper {

    private static final String[] HEADERS= {"X-Forwarded-For", "Proxy-Client-IP", "WL-Proxy-Client-IP", "HTTP_CLIENT_IP", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"};

    public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (String header : HEADERS) {
            String ip = request.getHeader(header);
            if (ip != null && ip.length() > 0) {                    
                return StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(ip)[0];
            }
        }
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }    
}
```

This will try al headers (in the given order) and if one exists return that. Else it will fallback to the `request.getRemoteAddr()`. Achieves the same with a lot less `if` statements.

I also factored in the case for potential multiple ip-addresses in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. It will always return the first element in the parsed array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am more interested understanding the use of "unknown","Proxy-Client-IP", "WL-Proxy-Client-IP", "HTTP_CLIENT_IP", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR". Is it necessary? Will it add any value if the spring boot code is deployed in PCF and accessed via Apigee proxy?

Comment: Those will probably not add anything as those are specific for WebLogic and PHP I believe. So unless you intend to use them they don't add anything. The reason for `unknown` I don't know, you should ask that the person who's code you are using :).