# How can I know real client IP in Websphere 8.5.5 and JAVA Web application

Tags: java, internet-explorer, websphere-8

My server receives requests from Internet Explorer. And my server is a java web application and it is Websphere 8.5.
I tried HttpRequestServlet.getRemoteAddr(), this was the IP of L4, not real client IP. I found that I could get the real IP from headers like X-Forwarded-For etc. In IE and Websphere, From which header can I get the real IP? or how can I get the real IP?

Comment: Check this out :- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797/how-do-i-get-the-remote-address-of-a-client-in-servlet]

Comment: If your load balancer is really operating at layer 4, you'll need to see what options your load balancer has for preserving the real client IP in the connection.  It can't be solved with HTTP headers in a layer 4 load balancer.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm gonna try tomorrow at my work.

Comment: @covener Thank you, It was becuase of L4 setting. I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now X-forwarded for IHS and Websphere version not require

So you should used layer 4 with load balance is `HAProxy` with open source or `F5` with load balance with money

and you can used `nginx` or `apache` for get IP for real IP X-Forwarded
Thanks and regards
tandn